# X11 forwarding using bsub

Tags: macos, ssh, x11-forwarding, r

I would like to run an interactive R job on a server.  I would also like to enable X11 forwarding so I can view my graphs.  However, I am having problems.
My laptop is a Mac OS 10.9.4.

I have tried ssh -X to the host, then

```
bsub -J Rlive -Is -XF -M 50000 -R "select [(mem >16000)]"
```

And now I get this error:

```
-bash-4.1$ bsub -J Rlive -Is -XF -M 50000 -R "select [(mem >16000)]" R
Job <562564> is submitted to default queue <medium_priority>.
<<ssh X11 forwarding job>>
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
waller@10.11.123.17's password: 
Sep  1 11:54:29 2015 26918 3 7.06 xagent main: initenv_() failed.
```

My DISPLAY variable seems fine.

```
-bash-4.1$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:15.0
```

is there something I have to do with Xauth?

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Thanks for the debugging suggestion, this is what I get:

```
waller@submaster:~>bsub -J Rlive -Is -XF -M 50000 -R "select [(mem >16000)]" R
Job <562888> is submitted to default queue <medium_priority>.
<<ssh X11 forwarding job>>
<<Waiting for dispatch ...>>
Sep  1 21:26:12 2015 33277 7 7.06 nios/main(): Nios running in standalone mode
Sep  1 21:26:12 2015 33277 7 7.06 nios/main(): Nios running in sbdMode mode
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33277 7 7.06 nios/acceptCallBack(): jobId 562888 opCode 562888
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33277 7 7.06 nios/acceptCallBack(): niosExecSSH(ssh -X -n 10.11.123.63 /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/xagent /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc 28918..)
<<Waiting for xagent to report remote DISPLAY on 10.11.123.63. Press Ctrl+C to terminate ...>>
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33277 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: Final cmdLine: ssh -X -n 10.11.123.63 /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/xagent /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc 28918 submaster 42107 /usr/share/lsf/conf
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: about to launch ssh -X -n 10.11.123.63 /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/xagent /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc 28918 submaster 42107 /usr/share/lsf/conf
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshPathName = ssh
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[0] = ssh
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[1] = -X
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[2] = -n
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[3] = 10.11.123.63
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[4] = /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/xagent
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[5] = /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[6] = 28918
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[7] = submaster
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[8] = 42107
Sep  1 21:26:15 2015 33313 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: sshArgs[9] = /usr/share/lsf/conf
The authenticity of host '10.11.123.63 (10.11.123.63)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 97:14:a7:a9:76:ba:8d:3a:5f:0a:ff:01:4a:8d:b2:ff.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '10.11.123.63' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
waller@10.11.123.63's password: 
Sep  1 21:26:29 2015 28928 3 7.06 xagent main: initenv_() failed.
Sep  1 21:26:29 2015 33277 7 7.06 niosExecSSH: ssh -X -n 10.11.123.63 /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/bin/xagent /opt/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc 28918 has exited.
Sep  1 21:26:29 2015 33277 3 7.06 nios/acceptCallBack(): niosExecSSH() failed.
Sep  1 21:26:29 2015 33277 7 7.06 kill_self(): Nios kill_self, exit_sig=0 exit_stat=-1
```

Comment: Can you try running it in debug mode? As described [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSETD4_9.1.3/lsf_admin/ssh_forwarding_troubleshoot_lsf.dita).  You don't have to change `lsf.conf`, just set the environment variables in the same shell that you do the `bsub`.

Comment: thanks - I added the output to running in debug mode above

Comment: Hmm.. It didn't provide any useful info.  A common cause for `initenv_()` failure is that the env vars `LSF_ENVDIR`, `LSF_CONFDIR`, or `LSF_SERVERDIR` are changed or lost in `xagent`'s environment.  Is it possible that ssh or the shell (.bashrc, etc) is changing them?

Comment: Is EGO enabled in your cluster?  (i.e., what is the value of the parameter `LSF_ENABLE_EGO` in `lsf.conf`?)

Comment: -bash-4.1$ echo $LSF_ENVDIR
/usr/share/lsf/conf
-bash-4.1$ echo $LSF_CONFDIR

-bash-4.1$ echo $LSF_SERVERDIR
/usr/share/lsf/7.0/linux2.6-glibc2.3-x86_64/etc

Comment: I"m not sure what LSF_CONFDIR is supposed to point to, but that one is empty.  .bashrc isn't changing these

Comment: Any chance you figured this out? Getting the same problem.